# Objective-C: Setting autoreleased objects to nil

Tags: objective-c

Is it safe to set an autoreleased object to nil? I know I don't need to release an autoreleased object but if I want the object to be released immediately to minimize memory use, can I set the object to nil?.

I may have read this somewhere a while back, but I can't remember where and I want to make sure that it is safe to do that.

Comment: Setting an autoreleased object to nil is safe, and in some cases it helps show your intent by code. However, setting the object to nil won't cause it to be released immediately. It will only be released once the autorelease pool is drained.

Comment: This is a very important concept to understand when it comes to memory management of very memory hungry processing.  There is an awful lot of objective-c literature that doesn't clarify this and I think a lot of developers that may confuse ARC with a traditional garbage collection model like Java.  I'm glad to verify my understanding of it was correct, because even I've questioned it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you're missing something pretty fundamental.  Setting an object to `nil` does nothing for you in terms of memory management.  Here's what's going on:[alt text http://gallery.me.com/davedelong/100084/Pointers1/web.png?ver=12783505480001](http://gallery.me.com/davedelong/100084/Pointers1/web.png?ver=12783505480001)

In this image, you have the stack (where your local variables live; it's more or less synonymous to where you currently are in your code while executing).  If you declare something like `int bar = 42;`, then `bar` lives on the stack.  On the right you have the heap.  This is global memory space that belongs to your application.  The heap was invented to solve the problem of scope: how to make useful information live beyond the scope of the current function (or method).  When we `malloc` space, we are assigned a slot of memory on the heap.  When you `alloc/init` an object, that object lives on the heap.  In Objective-C, all objects live on the heap.*  So let's consider this line:

```
MyObject * foo = [[MyObject alloc] init];
```

We really have 2 things going on.  The first is that we have allocated (`alloc`) a new chunk of space on the heap that's large enough to hold a `MyObject` structure.  Then we've taken the location of that chunk o' memory and assigned it into a local variable called `foo`.  In the image above, the reddish circle on the left is `foo`, and the reddish blob on the right is the actual `MyObject` (along with all of its data).  Make sense so far?

Here's what happens when you "set an object to `nil`" (`foo = nil;`)
[alt text http://gallery.me.com/davedelong/100084/Pointers2/web.png?ver=12783505490001](http://gallery.me.com/davedelong/100084/Pointers2/web.png?ver=12783505490001)

You'll see that the object *still lives on the heap*.  In fact the only thing that has changed is that your local variable `foo` no longer points to the chunk of memory on the heap.  It points to `0` (`nil`, `NULL`, whatever you want to call it), which is how we indicate that "this doesn't point to anything relevant any more".

In a nutshell: **setting a variable to nil has nothing to do with memory management**.  If you want to get rid of an object immediately, then use `release` and not `autorelease`.  However, even then that's not a guaranteed "destroy immediately", since something else might be `retain`ing the object (which is *the whole point* of using the retain-release memory management model).

Beyond this, once you're done with an object (and after you've invoked either `release` or `autorelease`), it's still a good idea to set the variable to `nil`, just to avoid potential problems.  In Objective-C we can safe send messages to `nil` without things blowing up in our faces (unlike Java). However, if you don't "nil out" a variable, bad things can happen.  Let's say `foo` is pointing to a `MyObject` instance, and then the `MyObject` instance is destroyed (you `release`d it, but didn't set it to `nil`).  If you try to invoke a method on `foo` again, your app will crash.  If you do set `foo` to `nil`, then your app will continue on its merry way.  It might not *do* what you were hoping, but that's a different problem entirely.

Welcome to the wonderful world of Objective-C memory management.

* except for local blocks, but then only until they're copied.  There are some other caveats to this as well, but that's getting into the arcane.

Comment: stepping it up w/illustrations, I see. +1.

Comment: @bbum i <3 omnigraffle.  i've also found that trying to explain the stack and the heap with just words tends to confuse people. (at least it did for me: visualizing what was going on was when it all clicked)

Comment: i wish the images weren't 404's now (since mobileMe closed shop). i'm a visual learner! :) anyway, awesome answer, upvoted!

Comment: @taber dang, and I've lost the originals.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is good practice as demonstrates that object is unused - i.e. no referenced data.

For what it's worth, you'll see it a lot in the sample code from Apple as well.

Comment: Sounds like you're confusing the garbage collector with autorelease pools. In a GC environment there is a benefit to setting to `nil` an object reference that would otherwise be persistent. But GC is often not used even on the Mac, and isn't available on iOS. There still may be potential benefits to setting `nil`, such as making sure no stale pointers are left around to trap the unwary coder, but it won't affect memory management.

Comment: @walkytalky agreed. I never said anything about GC. I just mentioned it's good practice. For the same reasons you mentioned - assured cleanliness.

Comment: Fair enough. But in that case it's hard to see what the phrase "it lets the memory pool know it's unused - i.e. no referenced data" is supposed to mean.